# Firebase FCM content_available via Firebase Cloud Functions throws error

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to send push notification via Cloud Functions.
This is the guide on how to do it from Firebase:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js

This is the payload I have

```
const payload = {
      "notification": {
        title: 'Title!',
        body: 'Body!',
        sound: 'default'
      },
      "data":{"score":"3x1"},
      "content_available": true,
    };
```

Now, this throwing an error, and when I check the log, here's the error:

```
Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid "content_available" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification".
    at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:130:23)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:465:23
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Messaging.validateMessagingPayload (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:462:21)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:204:37
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

If I removing the content_available: true, it works fine, so I know the code works.

I also tried to send this manually with CURL/POST request WITH content_available: true, and it also works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`contentAvailable` is passed in the `options` parameter of [sendToDevice(regToken, payload, options)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendToDevice).  Example code is in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#defining_the_message_options).  The documentation for [MessagingOptions is here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MessagingOptions).